# Cannot change int values created in main using a class function

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

**-I cannot change int values created in main using a class function-**

I am making a game and I have a function called `sideCollision` that checks if the player is touching a `pictureBox`,and if the player is touching the pictureBox,an integer called `Score` is incremented by 1.

Here is the function:

```
public void sideCollision(Control player,Control pointRadius,Control topPipe,Control bottomPipe,Control gameOver,int force,bool timer,int score,int pointRadiusCounter)
{
    if (player.Right > pointRadius.Left && player.Left < pointRadius.Right - player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > pointRadius.Top)
    {
        if (timer == true && pointRadiusCounter == 0)
        {
            pointRadiusCounter = 1;
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

The function detects the player touching the wall,but it does not increment the score by 1. I also have a message in my main saying "score has not been assigned to,and will always have its default value of 0".

I need to know how to change the score value using the function,because the function isn't changing the value of `Score`

Comment: Well yes, `score` is a parameter - a local variable. It's passed by value. Please read http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: How do you call this method? you could pass score in as a reference but then it would be better to figure out what you are actually doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use pass-by-reference in situations like this. Instead, you could in this situation use something like this.

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
    var score = 0;
    var pointRadiusCounter = 0;
    if (CollisionOccurred(...))
    {
        score++;
        pointRadiusCounter++;
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

public bool CollisionOccurred(Control player,Control pointRadius,Control topPipe,Control bottomPipe,Control gameOver,int force,bool timer)
{
    if (player.Right > pointRadius.Left && player.Left < pointRadius.Right - player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > pointRadius.Top)
    {
        if (timer == true && pointRadiusCounter == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for this being a little bit offtopic but this might help you avoiding problems like the one you have at the moment:

> I would consider to think about what variables need to be passes as a
>   parameter and what variables could also be accessible from all your
>   classes because their value will, whether it is changed or not, be the
>   same at any point of your code (for example lifepoints of the player,
>   score of the player, position of the player).
>
> Then you could transfer them into a own class (for this example the
>   "player" class), make those variables attributes of this class, and
>   make those accessible for your other classes via making the attributes
>   `public static`  or an `Singleton-class` if there is just 1 player in
>   the game.
>
> Passing an amount of variables as high as you do to
>   `sideCollision(...)` can cause a lot of trouble when your project
>   becomes bigger. Arranging and prioritizing your variables, methods,
>   classes etc. can help you to prevent this. So take your time and think
>   about what is important and where you need it and stuff like that.

Answer (score -1):

`int` is a value type. That means it's passed by-value and inside the function you have a *copy* of your original variable. You can solve this by passing it by-reference explicitly:

```
public void sideCollision(Control player,Control pointRadius,Control topPipe,Control bottomPipe,Control gameOver,int force,bool timer, ref int score, ref int pointRadiusCounter)
{
    if (player.Right > pointRadius.Left && player.Left < pointRadius.Right - player.Width / 2 && player.Bottom > pointRadius.Top)
    {
        if (timer == true && pointRadiusCounter == 0)
        {
            pointRadiusCounter = 1;
            score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would introduce an error into the calling code. But whilst I agree this would solve the issue, it may introduce bad habits into the OP's future code.

Comment: Hi, When I used the ref keyword I recieved an error upon trying to call the function,it said "the best overloaded match for sideCollision has some invalid arguements"

Comment: Dont worry,I didn't realize the ref keyword was also needed when calling the function,I thought it was only needed when making the function inside my class. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @ReubenWard please note that Microsoft does not recommend this method. You should try to minimize the number of `ref` usages. You could for example return a bool instead of counting up `score` and instead counting it up outside upon receiving a `true` from your method.